# Problem with an alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n!}{\pi^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to study the convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n!}{\pi^n}$$

Leibniz test has failed and absolute convergence too.
Any help?

Comment: Do the terms go to $0$?

Comment: Showing that the sequence diverges should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is always if the terms in the series themselves actually converge to $0$. If this is not the case, then the obviously the series will not converge (via [Divergence Test](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/divergence.html) ).

I will leave the verification that the terms do not tend towards zero to you, but notice that once $n$ surpasses 3, the numerator is growing faster than the denominator so you should be able to deduce that the summand does not converge to 0 in perhaps a more formal way.

Comment: For the OP: if you're having difficulty showing that the terms don't converge to $0$ in a more formal way, I recommend trying the ratio test.

Comment: If the term of the series does not converge to 0, i cannot conclude that the series diverge, it could also be indeterminate, right?
Also, i'm having issue to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \frac{n!}{\pi^n} = \infty$ due to the presence of $(-1)^n$, maybe rewriting the term like this? $\frac{n!}{(-\pi^n)}$

Comment: @user1825932 Forget about the alternating sign. It is enough to prove that the absolute value of the terms do not tend to $0$ (it tends to infinity).

Answer (score 0):

The series is divergent because the terms tend to $+\infty$ in absolute value. However, it is Borel summable:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{n!}}{{\pi ^n }}} & = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{1}{{\pi ^n }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - t} t^n \mathrm{d}t} }  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - t} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( { - \frac{t}{\pi }} \right)^n } \mathrm{d}t} \\ & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - t}\frac{t}{{\pi + t }}\mathrm{d}t}  = 0.207126866 \ldots\,. 
\end{align*}